# how can I do this is in C# read a file python version to c#?

Tags: c#

how can I do this in c# ? I am trying to get the bytes as python does , but using c# , but I dont have a clue how to do it in c# . I was using `File.ReadAllText(textFile);` , but it doesnt seem to fit my problem at all

```
import base64
data = open("sample.exe", "r").read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
print data
```

```cs
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = file.FileName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean to print the base64 encoding, not the original binary data, so...

```cs
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("sample.exe");
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
Console.WriteLine(encoded);
```